# Sprite Kit - movement of nodes with finger movement

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to make my `SKSpriteNode` to move smoothly with my finger. I have played many games which seems that the object followed my finger no matter how fast my finger went. But with my current code, i constantly lose control of my object and increase my speed would also lose control of it.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKSpriteNode *node = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:location];
        if (node.name != nil) {
            if (node.name == p1Name) {
                onP1 = true;
            }
            else if (node.name == p2Name) {
                onP2 = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        CGPoint preLocation = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];
        SKSpriteNode *paddle = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:location];
       if (paddle.name != nil) {
            if ((paddle.name == p1Name && onP1) || (paddle.name == p2Name && onP2)) {
                int paddleX = paddle.position.x + (location.x - preLocation.x);
                paddleX = MAX(paddleX, paddle.size.width/2);
                paddleX = MIN(paddleX, self.size.width - paddle.size.width/2);
                paddle.position = CGPointMake(paddleX, paddle.position.y);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

How do i make the `SKSpriteNode` to move smoothly with my finger when i touch and move on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You have your touchesMoved code set to only move the sprite if the touch is over the sprite. So as soon as you move your finger quickly that code won't execute since the there isn't a node beneath the touch. You need to set the "currently touched" sprite as a property during touchesBegan and then manipulate it during touches moved, or create different logic in your touchesMoved method.

Comment: So i should not get the node under my touch during `touchesMoved` method, and directly get the paddle object from my `touchesBegan` method?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your game, but that's the first option I outline. You may simply be able to remove the check in touchesMoved for the sprite and simply use the Booleans for paddle1 or paddle2 you set in touchesBegan as the only check in touchesMoved.